# Postgres: save common query as table attribute?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running Postgres 9.6. I have a user table:

```
 id                            | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                          | character varying           |           | not null |
```

And I have an `action` table:

```
 actioned_by      | integer                     |           |          | 
 category         | character varying           |           | not null | 
 t_actioned       | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
```

And I have a query that indicates how many days out of the past 30 days a user was active:

```
 SELECT d.actioned_by, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM 
  (SELECT date_trunc('day', t_actioned) AS day, actioned_by 
   FROM history 
   GROUP BY day, actioned_by) d 
 GROUP BY actioned_by
 ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

But is there a way I can annotate each user with this value, or create a shorthand way of referring to it?

It would be super useful if I could do things like "get me all French users who were active for more than 5 days of the month", without having to type in all the above each time.

Perhaps I need a view?

Comment: You've answered your own question, yes make a view.

Comment: @Richard from where this table history cames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way *is* making a view.

But you also could create a function on a composite type, a kind of virtual column:

```
-- Virtual column is a function that has a table type in its signature
CREATE FUNCTION last_activity("user") RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT d.actioned_by, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM 
      (SELECT date_trunc('day', t_actioned) AS day, actioned_by 
       FROM history
        --Filter
        WHERE actioned_by = $1.id
       GROUP BY day, actioned_by) d 
     GROUP BY actioned_by
     ORDER BY cnt DESC;    
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

--In order to use virtual columns you must qualify it with table name/alias
SELECT u.last_activity, * FROM "user" u;
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-COMPOSITE-FUNCTIONS).